# sql select distinct rows where item is like %

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Right now i am using an asp page to loop through a large table and see if one of the rows has at least one item in it where it is LIKE '1D%', however it does take a large amount of time and it needs to not only do '1D' but at least 30 other two characters likes as well. Is there a sql query that can make this into a table

thanks

OK guys to give you more of an idea of what I am trying to do I would like this query to go much faster

```
sql2 = "SELECT code FROM products "
set bs = MyConn.Execute(sql2)
    do until bs.eof
        if not bs.eof then
            sql3 = "SELECT code FROM brand"
            set ns = MyConn.Execute(sql3)
                do until ns.eof
                    if not ns.eof then
                        sql = "SELECT TOP 1 sku, MID(sku, 1, 5) AS brand FROM catalog WHERE sku LIKE '"&bs.fields("code")&ns.fields("code")&"%' "
                        set rs = MyConn.Execute(sql)
                        do until rs.eof
                            if not rs.eof then
                                response.write(rs.fields("brand")&"<br>")
                            end if
                        rs.movenext
                        loop
                        set rs = Nothing
                    end if
                ns.movenext
                loop
            set ns = nothing
        end if
    bs.movenext
    loop
set bs = Nothing
```

the output is something like this
1DZOO 
1FBAH 
1FDRE 
1FGRA 
1FRIV 
1FSCS 
1FSEC 
1FSUR 
1CALI

Comment: probably   what is the table structure like

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some sample data (including column types and names) and the input and output you're trying to obtain. I could answer this now  and say "Yes", but couldn't tell you how to do it because you didn't provide the information with which to do so.

Comment: WHERE MID(field, 1, 2) LIKE '1D' might help improve the speed - i.e., take a fixed number of chars and drop the wildcard.

Comment: Can you post a sample set of data, and what exactly you're trying to match?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT id FROM brand_check 'SELECTS 1D 1C 1F then do until rs.eof inside loop select top 1 sku from catalog where sku LIKE rs.fields('id') if not rs.eof then response.write rs.fields('id') = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another thing to consider would be to add Indexed Computed columns to the catalogue table, this would allow easy (and indexed) querying & more importantly - joining. Because SUBSTRING is deterministic in nature (Computed columns can only be indexed if they are deterministic), these columns would be just as fast once indexed (within reason), example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Example](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [SKU] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Computed_Product]  AS (substring([SKU],(1),(2))),
    [Computed_Brand]  AS (substring([SKU],(3),(2)))
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Computed_BrandCode] ON [dbo].[tbl_Example] 
(
    [Computed_Brand] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ComputedProductCode] ON [dbo].[tbl_Example] 
(
    [Computed_Product] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Example] ([ID], [SKU]) VALUES (1, N'ASdasdasdL')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Example] ([ID], [SKU]) VALUES (2, N'1231f2efwdsfas')
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_Example] ([ID], [SKU]) VALUES (3, N'sdf23re2fwdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
SELECT ... WHERE SUBSTRING(yourfield, 0, 2) IN ('1D', '2D', '3D', ...)
```

Comment: sql2 = "SELECT code FROM products "
 set bs = MyConn.Execute(sql2)
  do until bs.eof
   if not bs.eof then
    sql3 = "SELECT code FROM brand"
    set ns = MyConn.Execute(sql3)
     do until ns.eof
      if not ns.eof then
       sql = "SELECT TOP 1 sku, MID(sku, 1, 5) AS brand FROM catalog WHERE sku LIKE '"&bs.fields("code")&ns.fields("code")"%' "
       set rs = MyConn.Execute(sql)
       do until rs.eof
        if not rs.eof then
         response.write(rs.fields("brand")&"<br>")
        end if how can i make this faster?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't allow indexes to be used. Your other alternatives are to denormalize and create a derived field to hold those two chars, which would allow an index (with triggers to keep things in sync), or a long ugly `where yourfield like '1d%' or yourfield like '2d%' or yourfield like '3d%' etc...`

Comment: would it be just as fast to do the long ugly where? I could make a loop to build a string for the yourfield like and then put it into the sql query

Comment: it'd at least allow indexes to be used. you'd have to test which version is faster - there's sql overhead parsing, plus having to check EACH of those like conditions, etc... at some point it might be quicker to use a different construct because the overhead outweighs the gains.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are first loading all data in recordset and then looping it in ASP to filter it? No wonder it is slow! The SQL would be something like

```
SELECT
   Col1, Col2
FROM
   Table1
WHERE
   SearchCol1 LIKE '1D%'
   OR
   SearchCol2 LIKE '1D%'
```

This would also be not fast but would be much much faster than what you have now.

Comment: the 1D stands for a type of brand the catalog table is constantly updating with what items are for sale. so i need to have some way to display if we have any items from that brand in stock and then display them, the catalog field i am checking is called sku and the first two characters of the sku field declare what brand it is

Comment: So either the like or substring as posted by Marc should work for you.